# Issue connecting to Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm having an issue connecting to an Azure SQL Data Warehouse instance from within a corporate firewall.

I can connect to the server itself (i.e. the master database), and can telnet to both the server name and IP on 1433, but when I attempt to connect to the SQL DW database I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" (SQL Server Error 10061).

This isn't a permissions issue - the user has access to the database, and I can connect to it, using the same credentials, from other networks. Neither does it appear to be a firewall issue since I can connect to the master database.

Another peculiar symptom is that the version number of the server gets reported differently from different clients - variously as 12.0.2000.8 and 13.0.702 - although this doesn't appear to make any difference to connectivity.

This happens in VS 2013, VS 2015, SSMS 2012 and SSMS 2014.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Regards,

Matt

Comment: We also have this problem. The SQL Managment Studio that reports 13.0.702 can't see columns tree node when you expand out tables.

Comment: @MattConnolly, are you still hitting this issue?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, no - we've got connectivity now. We needed to open port 135 (tcp) on the client side. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into firewall issues from Azure.  Did you already run through these steps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-provision/#step-4-configure-server-firewall-access-for-your-client-ip

Comment: Thanks Nicolle. Yes, I've added the client IP to the firewall. I can connect to the master database, but not to the data warehouse DB. It does feel like a firewall issue because I can connect using the same credentials from some IPs but not others, but the firewall settings at the Azure end don't help. I'm wondering if perhaps the user databases communicate on a different port to the master database?